# How do I find which attributes my tree splits on, when using scikit-learn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have been exploring scikit-learn, making decision trees with both entropy and gini splitting criteria, and exploring the differences.

My question, is how can I "open the hood" and find out exactly which attributes the trees are splitting on at each level, along with their associated information values, so I can see where the two criterion make different choices?

So far, I have explored the 9 methods outlined in the documentation.  They don't appear to allow access to this information.  But surely this information is accessible?  I'm envisioning a list or dict that has entries for node and gain.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Directly from the documentation ( http://scikit-learn.org/0.12/modules/tree.html ):

```
from io import StringIO
out = StringIO()
out = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=out)
```

> `StringIO` module is no longer supported in Python3, instead import `io` module.

There is also the `tree_` attribute in your decision tree object, which allows the direct access to the whole structure.

And you can simply read it

```
clf.tree_.children_left #array of left children
clf.tree_.children_right #array of right children
clf.tree_.feature #array of nodes splitting feature
clf.tree_.threshold #array of nodes splitting points
clf.tree_.value #array of nodes values
```

for more details look at the [source code of export method](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/export.py)

In general you can use the `inspect` module

```
from inspect import getmembers
print( getmembers( clf.tree_ ) )
```

to get all the object's elements

[image: Decision tree visualization from sklearn docs]

Comment: Is "left" is always the "true" value and right is the "false"?

Comment: First link is broken

Comment: How do I get the samples value from the diagram?

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: what's the difference between these values(`clf.tree_.threshold` and `clf.tree_.value`)? `value` means metric value, e.g. gini index, gain etc.?

Answer (score 12):

If you just want a quick look at which what is going on in the tree, try:

```
zip(X.columns[clf.tree_.feature], clf.tree_.threshold, clf.tree_.children_left, clf.tree_.children_right)
```

where X is the data frame of independent variables and clf is the decision tree object. Notice that `clf.tree_.children_left` and `clf.tree_.children_right` together contain the order that the splits were made (each one of these would correspond to an arrow in the graphviz visualization).

Answer (score 11):

Scikit learn introduced a delicious new method called `export_text` in version 0.21 (May 2019) to view all the rules from a tree. [Documentation here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_text.html).

Once you've fit your model, you just need two lines of code. First, import `export_text`:

```
from sklearn.tree import export_text
```

Second, create an object that will contain your rules. To make the rules look more readable, use the `feature_names` argument and pass a list of your feature names. For example, if your model is called `model` and your features are named in a dataframe called `X_train`, you could create an object called `tree_rules`:

```
tree_rules = export_text(model, feature_names=list(X_train))
```

Then just print or save `tree_rules`. Your output will look like this:

```
|--- Age <= 0.63
|   |--- EstimatedSalary <= 0.61
|   |   |--- Age <= -0.16
|   |   |   |--- class: 0
|   |   |--- Age >  -0.16
|   |   |   |--- EstimatedSalary <= -0.06
|   |   |   |   |--- class: 0
|   |   |   |--- EstimatedSalary >  -0.06
|   |   |   |   |--- EstimatedSalary <= 0.40
|   |   |   |   |   |--- EstimatedSalary <= 0.03
|   |   |   |   |   |   |--- class: 1
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert this structure to a set of leaves, parents?

Comment: Be aware: `FutureWarning: The sklearn.tree.export module is  deprecated in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding classes / functions should instead be imported from sklearn.tree. Anything that cannot be imported from sklearn.tree is now part of the private API.`

Comment: I have lots of features and I'm working on jupyter notebook. Do you know which command I should use in order not to have everything on the same line (but "expand" on right)?